# How to make sure that there is only one of a given activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am not sure what is the best implementation to an app which should periodically check some condition and raise an alarm if the condition is met.

Let's say my main activity `MainActivity` has a "*start*"-button which starts the foreground service `CheckConditionService` which checks the condition once a second. If the condition is met, a new activity `AlarmActivity`, which has a "*stop alarm*"-button, should be started and a periodic beep should be started, too. If the user presses "*stop alarm*", the `AlarmActivity` should be destroyed and `CheckConditionService` should stop the periodic beep and continue the periodic condition check.

Now there could be several unusual use cases that I want to pay attention to:

1. The user could (accidently or on purpose) close the `AlarmActivity` instead of pressing the "*stop alarm*" button or it could be closed by the system because it was in the background for a too long time. In that case, the user should be able to re-open the `AlarmActivity` by clicking the app icon or the foreground notification of `CheckConditionService`.
2. On the other hand, clicking one of those should never create a state where more than one `AlarmActivity` is opened at once.
3. Maybe I forgot some other unusual behavior to pay attention to? Suggestions welcome!

**Question**: How is the best and cleanest way to do this? What should `CheckConditionService` call if the condition is met and the alarm is supposed to start? And what can `MainActivity` do in `onCreate()` 1. to find out whether  an alarm is currently raised and it should therefore start `AlarmActivity` and 2. whether an `AlarmActivity` is already opened and if yes, not to open a second instance of `AlarmActivity`, but to open the existing one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a `ForegroundService`
2. Create a static variable of, probably a `Boolean` type, if you want to check condition state, like: `CheckConditionService.isConditionMet`.
   Make sure to `Update` in whatever task you are running in that service.
3. Use a SplashScreen to determine which Activity should be opened depending on the result returned from `CheckConditionService.isConditionMet`.
   Here's a nice article: https://medium.com/@shishirthedev/the-right-way-to-implement-a-splash-screen-in-android-acae0e52949a
4. To prevent accidental close of `AlarmActivity`, you could disable `onBackPressed()`,
   However the user can always move away via the `Home Button` or swipe away (Gestures in newer versions).
   Point `3` can be handy there.
5. For using only one instance or single state of `AlarmActivity`,
   use `singleTask` flag in Manifest for that activity.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by "Make sure to Update in whatever task you are running in that service."?

Comment: If I use `singleTask` for `AlarmActivity` and if it is opened already, will each call to `startActivity()` on that activity just bring it back to front? Which functions inside `AlarmActivity` will be called in that case?

Comment: @Kolodez as you said, you check if a condition is met every second, so if it meets the condition, mark the static variable `isConditionMet` as true, else keep its initial value as `false`.
So what happens is, if the user closed the `AlarmActivity` by pressing home & the user opens from launcher or it is started with `startActivity()`, there won't be a new instance of the activity. & in a `Rare Case`, if the user opens the app & at that same time the condition was fulfilled, the user would be redirected to the `AlarmActivity` (check from SplashActivity)

Comment: Thank you. It looks like your suggestion works. :-)

Comment: Happy to hear that. :)